# Google Sheets formula to determine if text in a cell is italic

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible in Google Sheets to run a formula to determine if the text in a cell is *italic*?

Something like `isItalic(a1)` which would return `TRUE` / `FALSE`, so that the column could be filtered on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `=CHECKSTYLE(A1, "italic")`

```
function CHECKSTYLE(range, styleElement) {
    var arr = [],
        ret;
    var styleEl = ["line-through", "underline", "italic", "bold"]
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
        .getRange(range);
    var styles;
    if (styleEl.indexOf(styleElement) == 2) {
        styles = range.getFontStyles()
    } else if (styleEl.indexOf(styleElement) == 3) {
        styles = range.getFontWeights()
    } else if (styleEl.indexOf(styleElement) != -1) {
        styles = range.getFontLines();
    } else {
        throw "the 2nd parameter can only be " + styleEl.toString()
            .replace(",", ", ")
    }
    styles.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a.concat(b);
    })
        .forEach(function (el) {
            el === styleElement ? arr.push(["TRUE"]) : arr.push(["FALSE"])
        });
    range.getNumRows() == 1 ? ret = transpose(arr) : ret = arr;
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do something like the following in Google Sheets.

The .getFontStyle() method might be what you're looking for.

```js
var ID = 'yourDocumentID';
var name = 'nameOfYourSheet';

function myFunction() {
  
    var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID); // Selects your Source Spreadsheet by its ID
    var ssheet = sourceSheet.getSheetByName(name); // Selects your Source Sheet by its Name
    var range = ssheet.getRange(6, 10) // Selects J6 (just as an example)
   
    var fontStyle = range.getFontStyle(); // Tells you the font style
    ssheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(fontStyle); // writes the font style into A1

   var returnBoolean = range.getFontStyle() === 'italic' ? true : false; // checks if getFontStyle is true or false
ssheet.getRange(2,1).setValue(returnBoolean); // writes the boolean into A2 
}
```

A link to the docs can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfontstyle).

Answer (score 0):

// In cell place    =ISSTYLE((CELL("address",D4)&":"&CELL("address",D4)), "italic")

```
function ISSTYLE(pRange, styleElement) {  
                 // thanks to Https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54308576/google-sheets-formula-to-determine-if-text-in-a-cell-is-italic

                // thanks to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10629/how-to-pass-a-range-into-a-custom-function-in-google-spreadsheets/92156

    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(pRange);
    return range.getFontStyle() == styleElement;
}
```